# Can you start a sentence with "especially"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence, sentence-starts

I have this sentence in a text:

> Especially the foreigners are a very important group which requires special treatment and representation.

I feel it should read:

> The foreigners in particular are a very important group which requires special treatment...

Can you start a sentence with "Especially"? Why do I get the feeling that there's something missing in the sentence?

Comment: The short answer is yes but it's not formal. Especially here on ELU.

Comment: Especially when followed by "when" you may do this.

Comment: Perhaps nothing wrong with it, but it's not something I would do, and it would be unusual. Why not say *The foreigners especially, are a very important group...* ?